# Where is the folder storing the ResourceData files?

Tags: curated-data, files-and-directories

I wonder where would the file be stored in Windows when I use the function `ResourceData`. Since sometimes the data is quite large, I would like to have a look at the files and avoid duplicate downloads.

First, I thought that may be stored inside 11.X\SystemFiles, but I just can't find the large dataset file that I've just downloaded.

Many thanks!

Comment: Check out `$LocalBase`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get a resource object:

```
data = ResourceObject["GDB-9 Database"]
```

[image]

When we get back an object that formats as a summary box, there are often subvalues defined for various strings.  Here we can access the list of these strings with `"Properties"`

```
data["Properties"]
(*
{
    "Name", "UUID", "ContentElementLocations", "RepositoryLocation", "ResourceLocations",
    "ResourceType", "ContentSize", "ContentElements", "Version", "Description",
    "ContentTypes", "Categories", "Keywords", "MyAccount", "Attributes", "LatestUpdate",
    "DownloadedVersion", "DefaultReturnFormat", "AutoUpdate", "ContentElementAccessType",
    "ContributorInformation", "DefaultContentElement", "Details", "DOI", "Format",
    "InformationElements", "Originator", "ReleaseDate", "SeeAlso", "ShortName",
    "SourceMetadata", "WolframLanguageVersionRequired", "Properties", "DocumentationLink",
    "ExampleNotebook", "ExampleNotebookObject", "DefinitionNotebook", "DefinitionNotebookObject"
} 
*)
```

From this list `"ResourceLocations"` looks promising.

```
data["ResourceLocations"]
(* {LocalObject[
  "file:///Users/jasonb/Library/Wolfram/Objects/Resources/18e/\
18e5d5cf-cdea-428e-bfb2-bb619469019d"]} *)
```

Note that there won't be any data in that directory until I call `ResourceData[data]`.